# Why does PathBuf lose the current directory when I push a file onto it?

Tags: path, rust

Part of the current directory stored seems to be lost when I push a string onto a path. For example, if I do...

```
let mut path = "/test.txt";
let mut localpath = env::current_dir().unwrap();
println!("{}", localpath.display());
localpath.push(path);
println!("{}", localpath.display());
```

I get outputs on the console similar to

```
C:\User\JohnDoe\Desktop\testfolder
C:\test.txt
```

Does anyone know why `push(path)` might be deleting `\User\JohnDoe\Desktop\testfolder`?

Comment: I presume that was `"\\test.txt"`; `"\test.txt"` would behave rather differently, interpreting `\t` as HTAB.

Comment: ah my mistake it was /test.txt
Just fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.push):

> If `path` is absolute, it replaces the current path.
>
> On Windows:
>
> - if `path` has a root but no prefix (e.g. `\windows`), it replaces
>     everything except for the prefix (if any) of `self`.
> - if `path` has a
>     prefix but no root, it replaces `self`.

Your example falls under the first bullet point, where it replaces everything but `C:` with `\test.txt`.

The solution is to use a non-absolute path, ie, `test.txt`.